# Can I see which bitcoin node sent cli command

Tags: bitcoin-cli

If I am running a bitcoin node, and for example I run a `sendtoaddress` cli command, is it easy for anybody to see what IP that command came from initially

Comment: usually nodes allow rpc calls only from 127.0.0.1 or from whitelisted ip addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. If the node is running with `-debug=rpc`, then all RPC events will be logged, including RPC commands and where they came from.

Note that Bitcoin nodes do not communicate over RPC nor is the RPC interface typically exposed to the internet. Furthermore, the RPC interface is authenticated; connecting to it and being able to send a command requires knowing the username and password configured for that node.